# how do i manage the participant list for repeating surveys?

Tags: redcap

I have a small REDCap project with a non-repeating instrument (MEMBER) that registers participants, and a repeating survey instrument (VOTING) that captures participants opinions on an adhoc schedule (i.e. when I send the invitation). Not every member will be eligible to respond to every survey. There is an email address field in the MEMBER instrument that is selected in the 'survey settings' for the VOTING instrument. This field populates the participant list.

The first time I used 'survey distribution tools' to 'compose a survey invitation' everything was fine. Each eligible member was listed exactly once.

Thereafter, when I use 'survey distribution tools', and select the participants list belonging to my survey, the list has email addresses repeated according to the number of previously added VOTING instances. Similarly, the 'compose survey invitation' window shows an increasing long and duplicative list of email addresses that have to be manually sorted through to manually select 1 occurence of the participants email for each participant.

How do I stop the duplication? Currently I only have a couple of test member records and it is already unmanageable. With 20 or 30 members, the situation will be totally unmanageable.

So far the project is in DEV. Do I have to modify the survey settings to give a new survey title every time I want to send a new instance? Can I do that in PRD without moving back to draft?

Thanks for any assistance.

I have not thought of anything to try to eliminate the duplicate email addresses.

Comment: As interesting as it is, this sounds like it may not be on-topic for Stack Overflow, because it doesn't involve programming. If that turns out to be the case, consider posting it at Super User (see the links in the footer).